# Importing db table with emails into solr

Tags: mysql, solr, mariadb

I have a table with a field that contains a json string. I'm encountering an issue of records not being imported containing the ff strings:

> Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [txn_id=xxx0101,​ date_added=2018-07-27 11:58:11.0,​ jsonfield1={"email" : "user@host.com"},​ id=545,​ jsonfield2={"email2": "user02@host.com"},​ type=01,​ status=0,​ *version*=xxxx])

I noticed that the records that were indexed do not contain the email strings. Is there an escape handler for this when importing from a mariadb/mysql db?

Update: Just to be clear. My request for help is simple: The rejected data contains an @ symbol (an email) in a json field while other records that don't have it are imported normally. How do I tell solr to treat it literally or if I need to escape it. Please do not give me advice on database design or normalization or how I configured it. The design is deliberate. This is not the help I am asking for. I've already pointed out the potential cause. What I don't know is HOW to fix it. If it can't, I'm also fine with it as well.

Comment: You want to normalize the email fields, instead of having "field1" mapping to multiple values, you want fields named `email` and `email2` instead with the values directly under them. Exactly how to do that depends on how you're importing the values into Solr now.

Comment: @MatsLindh Those fields come from a third party consumer so normalizing it here doesn't make sense since the payload can vary from consumer to consumer. (no we don't get to tell them what to pass). We decided to make it a json string for now (this is still PoC).

Comment: Ok, but how do you want to search this nested information? And how are you actually indexing it as well? Edit the original question, so others will see it.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch We don't care at the moment (thankfully). We can do a search on the strings we want with those fields. Substrings are fine.

Comment: Fair enough. But it is still not clear how you are indexing it (json/xmol/solrj/dih) and what your import definition is. So, it is hard to tell when/where the json strings disappear. Theoretically, you could just treat the field (field1/field2) as text fields with ngram processing to pick up substrings. That will include some junk (quotes, columns, etc) but may be enough.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch I'm using the dataimport tool in solr and I've followed a tutorial how to import data from a mariadb table. I'm not exactly sure what you meant by "what your import definition is". There's only a db-data-config.xml, solrconfig.xml and managed-schema.xml file that I was told to modify. A problem arises when the columns with json entries have an "@" in them.

Comment: Your import definition is then db-data-config.xml. Update the main question, as this is too deep in the discussion for others to see. Solr Users mailing list may also be a good place to ask this kind of question, as it may need follow-up clarifications.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch all done. check it out

Comment: I am sorry. This makes no sense. Your DIH definition is for jsonfield1, your error message is for field1 with some parsing issues. Your dots do not connect. I think you are better off revisiting more closely what is happening and figuring out where exactly the problem is. Bisect the problem and all that.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch Sorry I was trying to obscure the actual implementation since this is company code. I corrected it but now I realize why you need all this info. My request is simple: How do I escape the '@' symbol that's causing the failure.

Comment: As long as the `@` is in a string, there is no need to escape it. The `@` is not the issue in your current structure, but having a deep object is (as already suggested). If you want to have Solr flatten the object for you (or tell it how to split the content), submit it to `update/json/docs` instead of the regular endpoint, and see [Transforming and indexing custom JSON](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#transforming-and-indexing-custom-json).

Comment: @MatsLindh I'll look into this. But let's just say this is the issue. Doesn't explain why other rows with the same exact json structure was successfully imported. That's why i presumed it's probably the email since it's the only thing that's different between the two.